# Print html page with current css

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to print some identified div in an html page with it's current css.

When I try to print the page via "ctrl+p" the css is included. But if I do this action via button the print screen doesn't include the css.

Any suggestion ? Thank you..

My code samples;

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="print">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssFile.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssFile.css" type="text/css" media="print">
</head>
```

I'm using same css files both link which include screen media attribute and print media attribute. Is this method suitable ? Should I write a new css for print in js function ?

I also tried adding css file in js function.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function(){
            var divId = "div";

            window.frames["print_frame"].document.head.innerHTML='<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="print"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cssFile.css" type="text/css" media="print">';
            window.frames["print_frame_ssd"].document.body.innerHTML=document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

.

```
<div id="div">
   content..
   <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the stylesheet is OK, you can check out this post

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

and the function you can try this

```
var prtContent = document.getElementById("your div id");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```

Give it a try and let me know it that worked for you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately still no css in the print screen.